# Maximize a function in Maple

Tags: maple

I want to maximize the following function in Maple:
$$
e^x (1+erf(\sqrt x))-1+2.303039319x^2 -0.632061419x-1.128379167\sqrt x-2.420022770x^{\frac{3}{2}}-2.118677733x^{\frac{5}{2}}
$$
for $x\in [0,1]$. I use "maximize()", but it doesn't run. I was wondering if anyone could help me about it.

Comment: No fractions are given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
restart;

ee := exp(x)*(1+erf(sqrt(x)))-1+2.303039319*x^2-0.632061419*x
      -1.128379167*sqrt(x)-2.420022770*x^(3/2)-2.118677733*x^(5/2):

Optimization:-Maximize(ee, x=0..1, method=branchandbound);

       [0.0128783107622822968, [x = 1.]]

Optimization:-Minimize(ee, x=0..1, method=branchandbound);

                 [0., [x = 0.]]
```

Let's look at a plot,

```
plot(ee, x=0..1);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.